# Get Google Classroom Meet Links

Tags: api, google-classroom, google-meet

How to get "Google Classroom Meet Links", Has anyone found a way to pull this info from the API or vs. ? I can get class codes, teacher emails, and links but can't reach classroom meet links.

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately this feature has not been incorporated into the API yet, as you can see from the [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/156772382) on [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).**

What you can do is giving a "star" to the issue to increase visibility and thus hopefully accelarate implementation.